# Nested foreach usage is not working in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="foreach : list1">
    <div data-bind="foreach : Land">
        <div data-bind="text : Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
var _json =[
    {
        "Land": {
            "Description": "BBA-Reman",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        }

    },
    {
        "Land": {
            "Description": "Star Mind",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        }
    }
]
self.list1 = ko.observableArray(_json);

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

why my nested foreach is not working ?

the moment i used with binding like this way then it is working

```
<div data-bind="foreach : list1">
    <div data-bind="with: Land">
        <div data-bind="text : Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/kxumu4rs/2/

Comment: `Land` contains an object and not an array, so you cannot use `foreach` on it but you need to use `with` as you already realized. But what is the problem with using `with`, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: there is no problem to use `with` but i like to know if i need to use nested `foreach` then what i need to change in code? can u plzz point it out? thanks

Comment: For use nested `foreach`, you need nested arrays. Currently you only have one big array in your JSON there is no other array in there: `Land` and `Zoning` and `Insurence` are all objects and not arrays.

Comment: if possible can u give me a sample code of nested json array where nested foreach usage will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data is not stored in a way that would support nested foreach iteration. `Land` is an `Object`, not an array.

If you want to iterate `Land`, it needs to be an array. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxumu4rs/4/

```
<div data-bind="foreach : list1">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Land">
        <div data-bind="text : Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
var _json =[
    {
        "Land": [
            {
                "Description": "BBA-Reman",
                "ID": 1,
                "CreateDate": null,
                "CreatedBy": null,
                "UpdateDate": null,
                "UpdatedBy": null
            },
            {
                "Description": "BBA-Reman 2",
                "ID": 2,
                "CreateDate": null,
                "CreatedBy": null,
                "UpdateDate": null,
                "UpdatedBy": null
            }
        ],
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        }

    },
    {
        "Land": [
            {
                "Description": "Star Mind",
                "ID": 1,
                "CreateDate": null,
                "CreatedBy": null,
                "UpdateDate": null,
                "UpdatedBy": null
            },
            {
                "Description": "Star Mind 2",
                "ID": 2,
                "CreateDate": null,
                "CreatedBy": null,
                "UpdateDate": null,
                "UpdatedBy": null
            }
        ],
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        }
    }
]
self.list1 = ko.observableArray(_json);

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

---

```
BBA-Reman
BBA-Reman 2
Star Mind
Star Mind 2
```

---

If your `Land` data is not truly an array of data, you should just leave it as is and use `with` as you had already posted:

```
<div data-bind="foreach : list1">
    <div data-bind="with: Land">
        <div data-bind="text : Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```